# RhinoMocks expecting complex object as a parameter

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mocking, rhino-mocks

I use RhinoMocks without problems for checking using AssertWasCalled if my method was called with simple parameters such as Arg.Is.Equal(1) etc.

However, it fails when I try to expect a complex object of my own creation, e.g.

```
Arg<CustomClass>.Is.Equal(CustomClassInstance)
```

Of course, I am well aware that this should not work because references don't match. However, my question is: how do I make it work? How can make RhinoMocks expect an object with certain values inside?

Answer (score 9):

You can use `Arg<T>.Matches (Predicate<T> predicate)` like:

```
mock.AssertWasCalled (m => m.Foo (Arg<CustomClass>.Matches (c => c.Foo == CustomClassInstance.Foo));
```